# root.destroy in tkinter for GUI not functioning properly

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, frame, root

I am trying to create a multi paged app here for a stupid little project but whenever I use the `root.destroy` function and then import method it words for about 3 clicks and then the program just closes. This is an example project with same code I am using to navigate in the acc project.

***main.py***

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

def move():
    root.destroy()
    import page2

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=400, width=400, bg="white")
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="white")
frame.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8, relx=0.1, rely=0.1)

button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Press me", command=move)
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

***page2.py***

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

def move():
    root.destroy()
    import main

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=400, width=400, bg="white")
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="white")
frame.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8, relx=0.1, rely=0.1)

button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Press me on 2", command=move)
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: while `import` does run the code in the module it imports, it would be kind of bad for it to do so literally every time with the same module because ya know, that wouldn't be particularly efficient, think about massive libraries. So from this you should understand that when you `import` something for the second time, it doesn't run the code anymore, it just references the already imported module from before, basically you shouldn't use `import` to run code like this, use functions and/or classes to make reusable code

Comment: A workaround for your problem could to put the whole page into a function. So just put everything on main in one function and call it "run". Then take the import of page_2 and put it all the way at the beginning, but not in the "run" function. You do the same with your page_2 and whenever you want to run one of the codes just do main.run() or page_2.run so you dont have to import the code again, but can simply run it. I will supply some code in an answer

Answer (score 0):

Your main:

```
from tkinter import *
import page_2
def run():
    window = Tk()
    def switch_to_page_2():
        window.destroy()
        page_2.run()
    # Create a button or something to call the function to switch to page_2
    window.mainloop()

run()
```

Your page_2:

```
from tkinter import *
import main

def run():
    # just run your code for your window here
    window_2 = Tk()
    def switch_to_main():
        window_2.destroy()
        main.run()
    # Also create a button to call the function here
    window_2.mainloop()
```

If there are any issues with this, please let me know.
For further information, see the comment I posted above...